# Show/Hide div based on drop down value

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm developing a function in javascript that should show/hide div based on selected value in the dropdown.

```js
function hide_show() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",init);

  function init() {
    document.querySelector('select#b2borprivate').addEventListener('click')=hide_show;
  }
  var zone = document.querySelector('select[name="b2borprivate"]')
  if (zone.value == "osoba_prywatna"){
    alert("test1");

    var x = document.getElementById("private_person");

    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      alert("test2");
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <label for="b2borprivate"><b>Osoba prywatna / Firma</b></label>
    <select class="form-control" id="b2borprivate" name="b2borprivate" onchange="hide_show()" required>
      <option value="">Wybierz</option>
      <option value="osoba_prywatna">Osoba prywatna</option>
      <option value="firma">Firma</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```

Alert one can be displayed successfully so the first condition works. The issue is about the second condition about `display.none`. It does not work.

Comment: `private_person` , can you show this id attached to ?

Comment: Check console for error. For example `x` can be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When fetching any tag using `getElementById`, it can't be accessed directly we need to access it using its 0th index.

You should update it to:
`var x = document.getElementById("private_person")[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I just fix it with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

PrivatePerson  is an array and should be accessed via indices

**Example**

document.getElementById('private_person')[0]